# конвертация json в java class

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Делаю погоду и столкнулся с проблемой конвертации json в java. Проблема в том что сайт http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/ дает базу данных городов в json который весит 30 Мбайт. И я ни на одном онлайн-сервисе не могу создать объекты java из json. Сайты просто виснут. Например этот http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.

Comment: А для чего классы создавать? Почему бы просто не работать с json?

Comment: У вас же в метках стоит gson, вот он и может преобразовать в нужный вам объект.

Comment: потому что я хочу перенести этот json  в бд и в дальнейшем работать с базой.

Comment: А Вы ему весь список что ли скармливаете? Достаточно один город сконвертировать - для остальных классы будут те же.

Comment: woesss спасибо, ваш ответ верный.